# HTML5 Web API 'fetch' POSTing file as body?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use the Web API [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) method to post a file as the request body?

```
window.fetch('https://www.example.com',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}),
        body: FILE
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
let input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', input.files[0]);

fetch('https://www.example.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
});
```

Comment: Doesn't that base64 encode it? Is there an equivalent of xhr.send(file)?